# Xcode 4.3 How do I save a region of my app screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-5

I am creating a native app on Xcode 4.3 and deploying to target iOS 5. The app is a basically a greeting card creator. I am having trouble figuring out how to save a portion of the screen from within the app.

What I want to do is this:

I am offering the user a button, that says "e-mail". when they click the button, the app should 'save' their card as an image and then 'paste' that into an email body.

The reason this is different than other answers on this website is that the area I want to save is made up of 4 'elements'. There is a background graphic that is the tilted card background, then there is a text field where users can type a message and then next to that is a picture area where they can choose their own picture to put on the card.

Here is a photo of what I am talking about:
http://marklopezdesigns.com/mydownloadz!/screenshotCard3.png

How do I save a 'composite' high res of these?

And then how do I get that into an email body message?

The reason i am asking how to 'save' it is because I want to be able to offer users another button that says "save to camera roll" and "send as message". I figure if I can understand how to save this high-res to a variable, then I should be off and running.

Thanks in advance for the help.

========

Here's the solution below

========
          ...so after a bit of fiddling. Finally got what I wanted. Here's the codebase I have in my method that fires upon touch of the "Save to Album" button:

```
- (IBAction)savePhoto{  

CGRect rect;  
rect = CGRectMake(11,50 ,305, 262);  
UIView *cardViewer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];  
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cardViewer.bounds.size);   
//make view background transparent  
cardViewer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.0];  
cardViewer.opaque = NO;  

//stuff items into a subview for capturing  
[self.view addSubview:cardViewer];  
[cardViewer addSubview:self.tiltedCard];  
[cardViewer addSubview:self.bigCardView];  
[cardViewer addSubview:self.cardWords];  
[cardViewer addSubview:self.photoView];  

[cardViewer.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];  
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();  
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([viewImage CGImage], rect);  
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];  
CGImageRelease(imageRef);  
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil);  

//put everything back where it belongs  
[self.view addSubview:self.tiltedCard];  
[self.view addSubview:self.bigCardView];  
[self.view addSubview:self.cardWords];  
[self.view addSubview:self.photoView];  

[cardViewer removeFromSuperview];
```

}

Comment: So do you want to do a screenshot using Xcode or using your app? If it's not Xcode, then please don't pretend it is.

Comment: I am pretty sure the OP wants it done programmaticly as part of the application.

Comment: Yes, i want this to be done programmatically as part of the application. I am offering the user a button, that says "e-mail this card" and when that happens, I want to capture an area of the app screen and place it in the body of an email.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ios how to capture a particular portion of screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915370/ios-how-to-capture-a-particular-portion-of-screen)

Answer (score 1):

To capture just an area of the screen, specify the bounds using `CGRectMake`.

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

In the example above we are capturing a 100px by 100px region beginning at x:50px and y:50px.

Comment: this works:    
 
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);    
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    
    
    CGRect rect;
    rect = CGRectMake(14,50 ,294, 203);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([viewImage CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil);

Comment: I am able to capture the region i want with the code from above...is there a way to not capture my background text image from my app? I can't necessarily target a single layer or object on my view, because i want a composite image of the greeting card, the text overlaid on it and the user's photo overlaid on the card. as shown here: http://marklopezdesigns.com/mydownloadz!/screenshotCard3.png

Comment: this is what the above codebse was able to produce:      http://marklopezdesigns.com/mydownloadz!/almostThere.png    this is great, but i don't want that tan background. That background is the bg to my app screen. If can just capture everything but that background, I will be 'golden'. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1657498 Now I get your question. The solution is simple. Place just the content you need to capture in a different view, and in the above code, instead of using `self.view.layer`, use `[yourNewView.layer renderInContext:context];`. Let me know if it worked. Thanks...

Comment: So i tried, to do what you said, but i'm still confused because i'm either capturing an empty view now. Or I can stick an image inside my new image view, as I have written below...but that's not a composite of 3 elements...instead it's one element (an image). I'll paste my code below in a separate comment.  I don't know where to go from here. I'm stuck .....

Comment: part 1 (OF 2) of my code, because there is a character limit on COMMENTS:      
    CGRect rect;
    rect = CGRectMake(14,50 ,294, 203);
    UIImageView *cardViewer = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cardViewer.bounds.size);  
    //i don't know what to put inside my imageView now ????
    [cardViewer setImage:bigCardView.image];//this is not what i want
    [cardViewer.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

Comment: part 2 (OF 2) of my code because there is a character limit on COMMENTS:   CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([viewImage CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil);

Comment: the reference to "bigCardView.image" is the name of my greeting card image....but if i get that image attribute, then i am not capturing the text box and user's photo overlaid on top of that greeting card image.

Comment: Put all your controls inside a UIView and then do the capture of that UIView.

Comment: thanks man.you are super cool. sometimes a person likes me just needs a little help walking through the steps. I got it!. I'll edit my post so others can share in 'our' code solution. thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

maybe get the picture of the layer by rendering the layer context and grabbing the image, I use this for displaying fancy animations

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: thanks you for the reply. However, i have already tried that codebase with no luck. What is returned to me when I apply this code is an image of the ENTIRE APP SCREEN as opposed to an arbitrary region of the APP screen. Perhaps is there a way to extend/modify this codebase to capture a 100px by 100px region beginning at the x:50px and y:50px for example?

Comment: Bijoy Thangaraj answered this for you, @user1657498 let me know if you still require assistance

Answer (score 0):

To capture just an area of the screen, use the **UIView or SubView** and just specify the bounds using CGRectMake.

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self.YourView.layer renderInContext:context]; // Make sure here you are using the  greetingcardView rather than self.view
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

**Note:** self.view will capture the whole screen so simply render the view wherever.