# how to capture a video in specific part rather than full screen in iOS

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation, video-recording

I am capturing a video in my IOS app using AVFoundation. i am able to record the video and able to playback also.

But my problem is that i am showing the capturing video in a view which is around 200 points height.so i expected the video would be recorded in the same dimensions.but when i playback the video its showing that the whole screen has been recorded.

so i want to know is there any way to record the camera preview which was visible to user only.And any help should be appreciated.

the screenshots:
([image: While Recording])
([image: while playback])

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by **which was visible to user only**???

Comment: The camera preview .

Comment: Have u tried this ? 
[ios how to capture a particular portion of screen][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915370/ios-how-to-capture-a-particular-portion-of-screen

Comment: @edo it is about capturing image from a part of the screen. but my problem is to capture the video not the static image.

Comment: @sateesh got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot think of video resolution in terms of UIView dimensions (or even screen size, for that matter). The camera is going to record at a certain resolution depending on how you set up the AVCaptureSession. For instance, you can change the video quality by setting the session preset via:

```
[self.captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480]
```

(It is already set by default to the highest setting.)

Now, when you play the video back, you do have a bit of control over how it is presented. For instance, if you want to play it in a smaller view (who's layer is of type AVPlayerLayer), you can set the video gravity via:

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = (AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer*)self.previewView.layer;
[previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect];
```

And depending on what you pass for the gravity parameter, you will get different results.

Hopefully this helps. Your question is a little unclear as it seems like you want the camera to only record a certain amount of it's input, but you'd have to put your hand over part of the lens to accomplish that ;)

Comment: thanks joeig for your answer. i got what you are saying.And i want to know is it possible to capture the part of the cameras input.If possible how to do that.

Comment: I don't believe that is possible. You might be able to create a composition after you've recorded input, but to tell the camera to ignore a portion of the input... I don't know how you would do that. Can you explain why you want only a portion of the input?

Comment: Its as per my app design. i can't provide any more information other than that.

Comment: Even if you could think of a situation that is analogous, it would help people to know how to address the question.