# CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0 Error only on device

Tags: xcode, core-graphics, xcode7

**Update: I am using XCode 7 Beta with Swift 2.0**

When I try to run my app on an iPhone I get these 3 errors:

```
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
<Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
```

When I enable to CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE variable I get this:

```
Backtrace:
      <<redacted>+40>
       <<redacted>+432>
        <<redacted>+144>
         <<redacted>+172>
          <<redacted>+332>
           <<redacted>+112>
            <<redacted>+820>
             <<redacted>+688>
              <<redacted>+356>
               <<redacted>+80>
                <<redacted>+808>
                 <<redacted>+344>
                  <<redacted>+420>
                   <<redacted>+104>
                    <<redacted>+284>
                     <<redacted>+556>
                      <<redacted>+504>
                       <<redacted>+1792>
                        <<redacted>+220>
                         <<redacted>+284>
                          <<redacted>+920>
                           <<redacted>+168>
                            <<redacted>+184>
                             <<redacted>+56>
                              <<redacted>+24>
                               <<redacted>+540>
                                <<redacted>+724>
                                 <CFRunLoopRunSpecific+384>
                                  <<redacted>+460>
                                   <UIApplicationMain+204>
                                    <main+164>
```

I'm not sure how to interpret this, I am not using any CoreGraphics content in my code, and the other similar questions had answers that did not work for me. I understand it can be difficult to help debug without code, but I can't figure out what code is related to this, so if anyone has an idea I can post more code.

Comment: see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508048/cgcontext-invalid-context-0x0?rq=1) it might be helpful

Answer (score 52, accepted):

From my experimentation, this seems to be due to defining `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` in `Info.plist`.

It happens on iOS 9 (beta & GM) but not on 8.4.

Comment: Wow thanks, that was the cause...I will submit a ticket

Comment: This is still happening in the released version of Xcode 7.0.

Comment: Had this still in XCode 7 GM, iOS9 GM.  But, check it out: Set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to **YES** (even though the status bar is hidden, which is why I set it to NO to begin with), and the warnings go away.  Crazy!

Comment: @Olie : Your answer worked for me. You should make it an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: [might help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31887785/3577656) and here is apple [thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13683) in which apple staff said,this warning can be avoided for now and it is a known issue.

Comment: I have reworded this answer so that it doesn't look like a "me too!" comment. See [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307568/560648) for more information.

Comment: I'm having the same issue in Xcode 8.2 (I'm rendering an UIImageView that will actually never be visible, serves only as a holder to merge two images together which is probably the issue as it points to use of CIImage instead of UIImage then).

Comment: Does not really have an effect in Xcode 8.2. Adding/removing this key makes no difference.

Answer (score 11):

At @JimRota's suggestion, moving this into an answer, since it was deemed helpful:

Had this still in XCode 7 GM, iOS9 GM. But, check it out: Set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to YES (even though the status bar is hidden, which is why I set it to NO to begin with), and the warnings go away. Crazy!

I then had to add this to my view controllers to keep the status bar hidden:

```
- (BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

For me, all my VCs actually inherit from the `ProjectNameViewController`, so that simplified it a bit.

Answer (score 2):

im getting the same thing on the xcode 7 GM release, i think ill simply ignore them since everything works but its pretty annoying even though they have admitted its a bug and just didnt fix it yet.
[Dev Forum Posting](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13683)

Answer (score 2):

from comments given above  , this is the real way to fix :

```
UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to YES in Info.plist
```

Answer (score 1):

I am getting this too (including the redacted part) when compiling my project on iOS9 beta5. Its fine when compiling on iOS8.

It happens right in my App Delegate, before executing any commands from

- `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {`

so it seems more likely to be an iOS beta problem than ours.

Comment: I have added that I am using XCode 7 beta and swift 2, but I think this was occurring on XCode 7 as well,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same type of bug when using non integer values as insets for resizable images, like this:

```
UIImage * image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"pill"]
             resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5)];
```

This caused this kind of logs. Using integer values fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had this error. It was because I created a function and forgot to add a return value.

```
-(void)doSomething
```

vs.

```
-doSomething
```

ugh.