# CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0 (Xcode 7 GM)

Tags: xcode, ios9, xcode7, suppress-warnings

I have this problem after I compiled my code with Xcode 7 GM.

According to Apple this is a bug, but it still seems to be an issue. Everything works fine, but is it possible to get rid of these errors?

> : CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>
> : CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>
> : CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.

[image]

Someone in other forums said something about status bar, but I don't have any success to eliminate the message. This is not a huge issue, but it's a useless "error". I'm using Interface Builder.

**Updated: I used Objective-C** if you use Swift, [maybe this is the question you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236204/cgcontextsavegstate-invalid-context-0x0-error-only-on-device)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0 Error only on device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236204/cgcontextsavegstate-invalid-context-0x0-error-only-on-device)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This also happens for me on 7 GM, but removing `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` from Info.plist fixed it for me, as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32446777/270420).

Update: Warning seems to be gone with iOS 9.2

Comment: Hi Ernesto, your solution worked for me too, however, what if I want the UIStatusbar to stay white? Did you find any solution to let the statusbar stay white without those errors?

Comment: Hi, I don't know what you mean exactly by 'white', but removing `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` means that the appearance of the status bar is now determined from the visible view controller, you have to implement [`preferredStatusBarStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/preferredStatusBarStyle) there and return the desired value. Note that if your content view controller is embedded in an navigation/tab controller, you have to implement it in the latter.

Comment: That only works if you have auto-layout turned on. If you have it turned off and cannot use UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance then you pretty much cannot change the status bar text to light.

Comment: Then I would just ignore the warning. I think someone in Apple's forum said it doesn't matter. I also see it on my iPhone on some system apps, so it shouldn't be harmful.
`Sep 23 15:56:43 iPhone SpringBoard[58] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.` ... `Sep 23 15:56:43 iPhone Preferences[223] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.`

Comment: [might help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31887785/3577656) and here is apple [thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13683) in which apple staff said,this warning can be avoided for now and it is a known issue.

Comment: After removing plist key **UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance** how i hide status bar?

Comment: @NilayShah: Implement `prefersStatusBarHidden` and return `false` similar as [I have described](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490837/cgcontextsavegstate-invalid-context-0x0-xcode-7-gm/32499501?noredirect=1#comment53101218_32499501) and in the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prefersStatusBarHidden).

Comment: @ernesto `prefersStatusBarHidden' method implements in all UIViewController's. Is there a only one way like .plist file.

Comment: @NilayShah No, there isn't.

Answer (score 9):

I'm drawing using `UIBezierPath`

Removing `path.fill()` removed the warning.

Comment: This would remove the color fill operation for the bezier path would it not, thus changing the functionality you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @sweetfa I thought so too but in my case, I was building the UIBezierPath only as the basis for a CAShapeLayer. I was using `setStroke()` outside any place like `draw(_ rect` where setting the stroke would actually make sense.

Answer (score 8):

I have found another cause for this error today.

When I wrote some drawing code in my View Controller class, these errors appeared. I realized that I have to create a UIView subclass and do the drawing steps in the override drawRect function. When I moved the drawing code there, all the errors disappeared.

Comment: Dude you just saved me! Thank you! Just have to say, in Swift 4.0 it's the draw(_ rect: CGRect) that has to be overridden.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good case to use the debugger. I set a breakpoint in my `main` and then used the F7 key to step through the code until the warning appeared. Turns out, there's yet another way this bogus error appears:

```objc
NSColor *myColor = colorFromRGBA(43,51,59,0.95);
[myColor set];
(self.window).backgroundColor = myColor;
```

It was generating the warning on `[myColor set]`. Evidently, I didn't need this and commented it out. At that point, the error went away. Your experience may differ, of course.

Comment: This was my issue too, except I was using [path stroke] on a UIBezierPath. That's the code that was generating this log for me.

Answer (score 1):

`UIGraphicsPushContext`, `UIGraphicsPopContext` worked for me

```
class CustomLayer: CAShapeLayer {
    override func draw(in context: CGContext) {
        UIGraphicsPushContext(context)

        ...Your code here...

        UIGraphicsPopContext()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Ayman Ibrahim said,

I commented out two lines and it worked like a charm.

```
    bezier2Path.close()
```

//        color.setFill()
//        bezier2Path.fill()

Answer (score -7):

Restart the device. It fixed my problem.