# I enabled CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE for "invalid context" error, but the whole stack is "redacted."

Tags: ios, core-graphics

Not sure what other info to provide. This is an iPhone app running under iOS 13.3. When I press the power button to send the phone into sleep and suspend the app, I get several "invalid context" errors on things like CGContextAddPath.

This is what gets dumped. What am I to make of this? As far as the error itself is concerned: I don't seem to be doing any of the things I've seen cited as instigators of this error. I'm not doing any CG drawing, for example.

```
2019-12-28 03:15:23.993511-0500 ARemote[426:36474] [Unknown process name] CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace:
  <<redacted>+612>
   <<redacted>+72>
    <<redacted>+184>
     <<redacted>+688>
      <<redacted>+444>
       <<redacted>+136>
        <<redacted>+604>
         <<redacted>+120>
          <<redacted>+124>
           <<redacted>+1896>
            <<redacted>+284>
             <<redacted>+480>
              <<redacted>+136>
               <<redacted>+304>
                <<redacted>+676>
                 <<redacted>+44>
                  <<redacted>+144>
                   <<redacted>+552>
                    <<redacted>+96>
                     <<redacted>+216>
                      <<redacted>+116>
                       <<redacted>+76>
                        <<redacted>+392>
                         <<redacted>+124>
                          <<redacted>+256>
                           <<redacted>+336>
                            <<redacted>+276>
                             <<redacted>+280>
                              <<redacted>+1000>
                               <<redacted>+132>
                                <<redacted>+60>
                                 <<redacted>+120>
                                  <<redacted>+440>
                                   <<redacted>+168>
                                    <<redacted>+468>
                                     <<redacted>+672>
                                      <<redacted>+220>
                                       <<redacted>+464>
                                        <<redacted>+544>
                                         <<redacted>+120>
                                          <<redacted>+232>
                                           <<redacted>+184>
                                            <_dispatch_client_callout+16>
                                             <_dispatch_block_invoke_direct+232>
                                              <<redacted>+40>
                                               <<redacted>+404>
                                               <<redacted>+28>
                                               <<redacted>+24>
                                               <<redacted>+80>
                                               <<redacted>+180>
                                               <<redacted>+1080>
                                               <CFRunLoopRunSpecific+464>
                                               <GSEventRunModal+104>
                                               <UIApplicationMain+1936>
                                               <main+76>                                               <<redacted>+4>
```

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236204/cgcontextsavegstate-invalid-context-0x0-error-only-on-device/32446777#32446777

Comment: Seems like that's a private API of iOS that draws the status bar, that's why it's `<redacted>`.

Comment: Thanks for that info and link. I doubt that it's quite the same problem that the other question cites (app-controlled status bar) because the view controllers in question in my app don't use that.